# Android spinner - always select index 0

Tags: android

I have a spinner in my layout and I would like to select only first option (index 0) no matter user selection have been made. I have some code, but there is some text flicker when spinner change rapidly from user selection to index 0. So I would like to make no user selection / select index 0 at first.
This is my code:

```
final Spinner onespinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner0);
String[] items0 = new String[] { "item 1", "item 2", "item 3","item 4","item 5" };
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter0 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, items0);
onespinner.setAdapter(adapter0);
onespinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // automaticaly select first option
        onespinner.setSelection(0,true);
        // but there is some text flicker
    }
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
});
```

Comment: You have a spinner with options but you want your users to select only one thing??

Comment: Yes, is like a reminder

Comment: Then why don't you just have a `TextView` that tells them when they're going to be reminded instead of giving false hope of having an option?

Comment: I have several options available that will solve your problem but you can only get the first one which is, you shouldn't use a spinner for this.

Comment: You mean that this is like a list of texts that the purpose is like reminder for the user right? So user can peek for all of the texts from this spinner.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the spinner? It's not clear why you're asking for this functionality.

Comment: I don't necessarily want to be a spinner, I just want it you to behave like that, a button showing a popup option window on click event.

Comment: use AlertDialog if you just need a popup to show other items and Use a button with text(your first option) to trigger it.